# IOS offline browsing with DB

Tags: ios

I am creating one application. This application have two databases.

1. Local Database (In the mobile)
2. Cloud Database

Both databases are automatically syncing. 
Through my application when I Browse the page I want to keep that page in my phone. again When I browsing without internet (Offline) I want to access that store files. 
My problem is without internet offline browsing (stored web pages) need to access my local database and give the informations.

Eg. I want to search something. if it is internet search cloud database. (Same time store the web page HTML content in the phone). Offline searching want to access the local database. In here it want to use the stored HTML content. But access the local database.

It is possible or not? I am a beginner. Please guide me

Comment: Before the down vote tell me the reason....

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380 ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use scripts/code on server to connect to db on the server when you are online. Even if you download and save you 'HTML' file locally, when you load it in UIWebView it is not going to start fetching data from your local sqlite db. (hence all the down votes i guess)

So simply put, what you are asking is not possible.

However, an alternative which may work, subject to your app requirements, is to change your app code to always perform searches on local database and instead of HTML show search results using native UI. As you claim that your local db syncs with the sever automatically, when you are online, after your db is up to date, your search results will fetch fresh, synced up data from local db. Since your search uses local db you'll be getting last synced data when you are offline.